# Making a Java Runnable JAR that downloads platform-specific libraries

Tags: download, fatjar, javaexec-gradle-plugin

I have a small Java (Kotlin) app.  It requires some big libraries like openblas and opencv.  I'd like to package it up in a drag-and-drop executable JAR file, but when I build a fatJar, it includes the libraries for all possible platforms, and ends up being over 600MB.

That is way too huge!  I'd much prefer a small app that downloads the appropriate libraries for the user's platform when you run it for the first time.  Is this a standard?  I can't assume the end user will have Gradle or Maven installed, just that they have a JRE installed.

I tried what I think is the latest fatJar for `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
val fatJar = task("fatJar", type = Jar::class) {
    archiveBaseName.set("${project.name}-fat")
    manifest {
        attributes["Implementation-Title"] = project.name
        attributes["Implementation-Version"] = project.version
        attributes["Main-Class"] = application.mainClass
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from(configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().map { if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) })
    with(tasks["jar"] as CopySpec)
}
```

And then checked which libraries were in the JAR file: it *was* behaving correctly and not duplicating Kotlin versions or anything else bad.

Comment: Hi @BenjaminH, ```it includes the libraries for all possible platforms```. What do you refer as platform here?

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian that's the thing - I don't know what platform the end user is on.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. When you refer to platform, do you mean Operation System or JVM programming language like Kotlin/Groovy? I believe Java depdencies/libraries are platform independent. So it doesn't matter which operating system is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/blob/master/tutorials/Native_distributions_and_local_execution/README.md#basic-usage is what I'm looking for.  I haven't got it working yet, but it sounds like the feature set.